# How to filter dependent selects with React

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown

I wanted to know how to change the options of the selects according to the selected option of the select before with React and exactly component function and not class. For example when I choose a category, it must show me in the select according to the project options which belongs to this category. I have a hard time finding a solution for this I searched several times on youtube and google but without result. Please help me if you know how to code this part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have two lists: the first list is used to render the highest level select input. Once an item is selected from the first level input, you try to find the selected item in the second list which is actually in the form of an object i.e. key-value pairs here for simplicity. I have a sublist for every key. So we can render a different sublist for every item selected from the top-level list.

In this way, you can have as many levels as you like. You may even employ recursion for this purpose and have all your options in the form of a tree.

```js
const App = () => {
  const continents = ["", "Africa", "Europe"];
  const countries = {
    Africa: ["Egypt", "Kenya", "South Africa"],
    Europe: ["United Kingdom", "Germany", "France"]
  };
  const [selectedContinent, setSelectedContinent] = React.useState();
  const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = React.useState();
  
  
  return (
    <div>
      <select onChange={(e) => setSelectedContinent(e.target.value)}>
        {continents.map(continent => (
          <option key={continent}>{continent}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      {countries[selectedContinent] &&
        countries[selectedContinent].length > 0 && (
        <select onChange={(e) => setSelectedCountry(e.target.value)}>
          {countries[selectedContinent].map(country => (
            <option key={country}>{country}</option>
          ))}
        </select>
      )}
    </div>
  )


}


ReactDOM
  .createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
  .render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```